# Is there a way to only scaleX with svelte transition?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-transition

So I want to create a transition when my element will be out. I want the transition to only scaleX (from 1 to 0), because I know that in svelt there is a scale transition but it scales the element in its entirety.

Here is how I use the scale transition for now :

```
{#if show}
    <div out:scale="{{duration: 1000}}" data-title="picture portfolio" data-scroll-speed="1">
      <img
        on:click={transition}
        on:keydown={transition}
        src="pictures/portfolioPicture/landing.png"
        alt="photography portfolio landing"
      />
    </div>
  {/if}
```

In the JS I just toggle the show variable.
Any help will be welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [custom transition](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-transition-fn-custom-transition-functions) - In out transitions `t` runs from 1 to 0

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8749c73f127b4d429062dde5c16eba03?version=3.55.1)

```
<script>
    import { cubicOut } from 'svelte/easing';
    
    let show = true
    
    function customScale(node, options) {
        return {
            duration: options.duration,
            easing: cubicOut,
            css: t => `transform:scaleX(${t}); transform-origin: top left;`
        }
    }   
</script>

<button on:click={() => show = !show}>
  toggle show
</button>

{#if show}
<div out:customScale="{{duration: 1000}}" data-title="picture portfolio" data-scroll-speed="1">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1121395911849062400/7exmJEg4_400x400.png"
             alt="photography portfolio landing"
             />
</div>
{/if}
```